# CodeIgniter Set Form Validation Redirect URL

Tags: codeigniter

When the form doesn't get run because some of the fields are missing the form validator redirects back to current controller/method by default. This means that if I've set a route for 'signup' that routes to auth/register I want it to redirect back to the route path not the actual controller path.

Any suggestions?

```
function register() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');     
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                // Do some stuff here
        } else {

            $data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

            $data['name'] = array('name' => 'name',
                'id' => 'name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('name'),
            );
            $data['description'] = array('name' => 'description',
                'id' => 'description',
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('description'),
                'class' => 'form-textarea',
            );
            $data['email'] = array('name' => 'email',
                'id' => 'email',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
            );

            $data['contact'] = array('name' => 'contact',
                'id' => 'contact',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('contact'),
            );

            $data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
                'id' => 'password',
                'type' => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
            );
            $data['password_confirm'] = array('name' => 'password_confirm',
                'id' => 'password_confirm',
                'type' => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
            );

            $this->load->view('organisations/create', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the form validator does not redirect anywhere by default - you branch off of the result of `form_validation->run()`' and load the view there or redirect on your own, can you elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would set the default behavior to what you want if the form is not submitted or if there are validation errors and then redirect if the user if the form is successfully processed.

i.e.

```
function register() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');     
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        // Do some stuff here to process the form
        // Maybe set the success flash message
        // Then redirect
        redirect('organizations/login');
    } else {

        $data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

        $data['name'] = array('name' => 'name',
            'id' => 'name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('name'),
        );
        $data['description'] = array('name' => 'description',
            'id' => 'description',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('description'),
            'class' => 'form-textarea',
        );
        $data['email'] = array('name' => 'email',
            'id' => 'email',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
        );

        $data['contact'] = array('name' => 'contact',
            'id' => 'contact',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('contact'),
        );

        $data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
        );
        $data['password_confirm'] = array('name' => 'password_confirm',
            'id' => 'password_confirm',
            'type' => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
        );
    }

    $this->load->view('organisations/create', $data);
}
```

This may require you to change the way you structure some things now, but I've found this to be the easiest way to handle this situation.

Comment: +1, I'd agree here. The form needs to be shown on this `register` method both without a form submit and when validation fails. By redirecting if validation passes, you keep control of the flow for the user.

Comment: It's more what happens when the validation fails. I want to redirect back to the route url not the controller/method which is what happens

Comment: Why don't you just put in a redirect in the fail condition? If it's in the same controller and you want to keep your `$data` var, you can call the method (`$this->method()`) and pass `$data` as a parameter.